# Matlab fprintf - What is faster - writing all output or only a few using if with modulo?

Tags: performance, matlab, stdout

In my special case, I want to decide this for matlab. Is it faster (inside a for loop with ~250.000 runs) with the "if", so fprintf is only used 250 times?

```
for i=1:250042
  if ~(mod(i, 1000))
    fprintf(<something to standard output>);
  end
end
```

I know for programming in C, programs were much slower, when printing to the standard output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I prefer to not use `i` as an index, as it serves to represent the imaginary number in Matlab.
Your question is easy to test:

```
tic
for jj=1:250042
  if ~mod(jj,1000)
    disp('Hello')
  end
end

a=toc;

tic

for jj=1:250042
  if ~mod(jj,100)
    disp('Hello')
  end
end

b=toc;
clc
disp(a)
disp(b)
```

gives

```
0.0295
0.0736
```

so the answer is: yes, it is faster to print less.

Answer (score 3):

It is much slower to print everything. By profiling the following code

```
clear all
clear classes

for i=1:250042
    if ~(mod(i, 1000))
        fprintf(['current loop: ', num2str(i), '\n']);
    end
end

for i=1:250042
    fprintf(['current loop: ', num2str(i), '\n']);
end
```

I found the following:

```
   time   calls  line
< 0.01       1    1 clear all 
< 0.01       1    2 clear classes 
                  3 
             1    4 for i=1:250042 
  0.13  250042    5     if ~(mod(i, 1000)) 
  0.12     250    6         fprintf(['current loop: ', num2str(i), '\n']); 
           250    7     end 
  0.24  250042    8 end 
                  9 
             1   10 for i=1:250042 
 37.90  250042   11     fprintf(['current loop: ', num2str(i), '\n']); 
  0.47  250042   12 end
```

Printing everything is orders of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 3):

Calls to fprintf have considerable overhead, especially for small write operations. For instance, executing the following code:

```
fid = fopen ( 'a.txt' , 'w+' );

timeStart1000 = tic;
for ( ii = 1 : 10 )
  for ( iii = 1 : 100 )
    b = num2str ( ii );
    fprintf ( fid , b );
  end
end
timeStop1000 = toc ( timeStart1000 );

timeStart10 = tic;
for ( ii = 1 : 10 )
  c = '';
  for ( iii = 1 : 100 )
    c = [ c , num2str(ii) ];
  end
  fprintf ( fid , c );
end
timeStop10 = toc ( timeStart10 );
```

There is a significant time difference between 1000 and 10 calls to fprintf: `timeStop1000 = 0.1816` vs. `timeStop10 = 0.0765`.